# How to get the space consumed by a set of records in a table?

Tags: mysql, sqlperformance

I have a table called HUGETABLE. I want to get the size consumed by a set of records in HUGETABLE under some Select where criteria. I am currently using the following query for getting the table size in KBS , is there any Other improved query other than this? :

```
SELECT SUM(LENGTH(IFNULL(translation_logs.GUID,0))+
LENGTH(IFNULL(HUGETABLE.ID,0))+
LENGTH(IFNULL(HUGETABLE.SEQUENCENO,0))+
LENGTH(IFNULL(HUGETABLE.BID,0))+
LENGTH(IFNULL(HUGETABLE.TID,0))+
LENGTH(IFNULL(HUGETABLE.TABLENAME,0))+
LENGTH(IFNULL(HUGETABLE.MODIFIEDDATE,0))+
LENGTH(IFNULL(HUGETABLE.MODIFIEDBY,0))+
LENGTH(IFNULL(HUGETABLE.UPDATEXML,0))+
LENGTH(IFNULL(HUGETABLE.BESTIDENTIFIERVALUE,0)))/1024  AS "Total Size in KB" 
FROM HUGETABLE
WHERE TID = 'myvalue';
```

and TID is the index field

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making a huge query, you can check via the maximal size of each field. If you have VARCHAR, it'll be a bit difficult and in that case you have to do a selection.

According to [this documentation page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html), an INT takes 4 bytes, a DATE 3 bytes, etc. So with 5 INT (your 5 first fields), 1 DATE and 4 VARCHAR (I'm guessing not sure about your table structure), you just have to do something like:

```
 SELECT 4*5 + 1 * 3 + (LENGTH(TABLENAME)+2) + (LENGTH(MODIFYBY)+2) + ...
 FROM HUGETABLE
 WHERE TID = 'myvalue';
```

If you want to also take the space used by the index, it's a bit more difficult, and I'm not informed enough about it.